# SQL encoding issue: When Updating data in the DB(UPDATE) characters become gibrish

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, pdo

I'm using pdo via php to update my sql.
When I put primary values in the DB the encoding seems to be fine.
but for some or other reason when I use sql UPDATE command
to change the data im getting gibrish.
to be sure nothing is wrong with the way im passing the data I changed the query im sending to be static data that I control, and it still gives me gibrish as a result after updating.

This is how im sending my data:

```
function ConnectToSQLAndGetDBConnSTRVar() {
    try {
    $dbname = "db";
    $serverName = ".\SQLEXPRESS";  
    $username = "user";
    $pw = "pass"; 
    $dbh = new PDO ("sqlsrv:server=$serverName;Database=$dbname","$username","$pw"  );
    return $dbh;
    } 
    catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Failed to get DB handle: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    exit;
    }    
} 
  $db = ConnectToSQLAndGetDBConnSTRVar;
  $NewQuery = "UPDATE subtopics SET SubTopic_Name = 'תוכן' WHERE SubTopic_ID=1";
  $db->query($NewQuery);
```

its possible you will see my content as giberish to but I assure u it is not, its just in another language..

Note: that I can't use charset=utf-8 it gives me an error :
An invalid keyword charset was specified in the dsn string

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to the `$driver_options` array (last argument of `new PDO()`) :

```
ARRAY(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET CHARACTER SET utf8")
```

Answer (score 0):

You're storing Unicode data in an `NVARCHAR` column. You need to denote strings as Unicode, e.g.

```sql
$NewQuery = "UPDATE subtopics SET SubTopic_Name = N'תוכן' WHERE SubTopic_ID=1";
--------------------------------------------------^ this N is important
```